# Restore only one partition of Windows Backup

Tags: windows-7, mac, partitioning, backup

I have a MacBook Pro with an HD partitioned. This HD was divided in two partitions: the first was about 650 GB, with OS X installed, and the second one (created with BootCamp Assistant) was about 100 GB, with Windows 7 installed.

I needed more space for Windows, so I decided to backup the Windows partition using the Windows backup tool, from Control Panel.

I created an image of my partition, stored it in an external HD, and now I'm trying to use it.

In order to give more space to Windows, I formatted the HD, and recreate a new partition table, with the first partition of about 250 GB (with OS X) and the second of the exactly size of the previous partition in which was installed Windows (about 100 GB); thre rest was empty space.

In the second, I tried to restore the Windows backup.

I plugged in the Windows Installation CD (with the HD with the backup connected to the computer), and select the option "Repair your computer". Then, I choose the image of the backup (automatically recognized), and I try to restore it.

The problem is that now the System Recovery Tool wants to format all the HD, in order to install only Windows! In this way, I should lose everything, also the MacOS partition!

Is there a way to install the backup only in the Windows partition?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to restore your backup , there is an option where you can exclude the disks that you don't want to format or repartition. Check this:
[Windows System Backup and Restore](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/675-system-image-recovery.html)

Comment: Yes, I know. There is a checkbox labled "Format and repartion disk", that is grayed out and enabled. So I cannot disable that option, and I'm forced to format everything!